# truncate the string to 1 MB size limit

Tags: javascript

I need to cut the string - basically if the string if longer that 1 MB I should cut it to this size.

I am using these functions to check the string size

```
function __to_mb(bytes) {
   return bytes / Math.pow(1024, 2)
}

function __size_mb(str) {
  return __to_mb(Buffer.byteLength(str, 'utf8'))
}
```

Then I check the size of string like this

```
if (__size_mb(str) > 1) { /* do something */ }
```

But how to cut it?

Comment: but it cuts to amount of characters. I want to 1 MB in size.

Answer (score 0):

A Javascript string consists of 16-bit sequences, with some characters using *one 16-bit sequence* and others needing *two 16-bit sequences*.

There is no easy way to just take an amount of bytes and consider it done - there might be a *2x* 16-bit character at both sides of the cut-off location, which would then be cut in half.

To make a safe cut, we can use `str.codePointAt(index)` which was introduced in ES2015. It knows which characters are 16-bit and which are *2x* 16-bit. It combines either 1 or 2 of these 16-bit values into an integer result value.

- If `codePointAt()` returns a value <= `2^16-1` then we have a 16-bit character at offset `index`.
- If `codePointAt()` returns a value >= `2^16` then we have a *2x* 16-bit character at offsets `index` and `index+1`.

Unfortunately this means going through the entire string to assess each index. This may seem awkward, and it may even be slow, but I am not aware of a faster or smarter way of doing this.

**Demo:**

```js
var str = "abçdéΩfgh"; // string of 13 characters
console.log("str.length    = " + str.length); // shows 17 because of double-width chars
console.log("size in bytes = " + str.length * 2); // length * 2 gives size in bytes

var maxByteLengths = [8, 16, 24, 32, 40];
for (var maxBytes of maxByteLengths) {
  var data = safeCutOff(str, maxBytes);
  console.log(maxBytes + " bytes -> " + data.text + " (" + data.bytes + " bytes)");
}

function safeCutOff(str, maxBytes) {
  let widthInBytes = 0;
  for (var index = 0; index < str.length; /* index is incremented below */ ) {
    let positionsUsed = str.codePointAt(index) <= 0xFFFF ? 1 : 2;
    newWidthInBytes = widthInBytes + 2 * positionsUsed;
    if (newWidthInBytes > maxBytes)
      break;
    index += positionsUsed;
    widthInBytes = newWidthInBytes;
  }
  return { text: str.substring(0, index), bytes: widthInBytes };
}
```